# jQuery xml parsing

Tags: jquery, xml

this is a bit cheeky, I'm effectively asking you to write code for me but I'm having hard time to extract certain data from a xml result

here is the xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <GeocodeResponse>
     <status>OK</status> 
     <result>
         <type>route</type> 
         <address_component>
             <long_name>xxxxxxxxxxx</long_name> 
             <short_name>xxxxxxxxxxx</short_name> 
             <type>administrative_area_level_3</type> 
             <type>political</type> 
         </address_component>
     </result>
     <result>
         <type>postal_code</type> 
         <address_component>
            <long_name>xxxxxxxxxxx</long_name> 
            <short_name>xxxxxxxxxxx</short_name> 
            <type>administrative_area_level_2</type> 
            <type>political</type> 
         </address_component>
     </result>
 </GeocodeResponse>
```

How can I get long_name of type administrative_area_level_3 on address_component of result type route with jquery?

Comment: That last line is supposed to be a close tag for `<GeocodeResponse>`, right?

Comment: yes, edited my question to reflect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: "XMLFile.xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('type').each(function () { // find all "type" tag in XML
                if ($(this).text() == 'administrative_area_level_3') { // in here $(this) is our "type" tag
                    var result = $(this).parent().find('long_name').text(); // get result
                    $('#result').html('The Result is: ' + result) // write result
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

live example is [here](http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/xml)

Comment: thanks, it works fine on ie but not on firefox or pera with dummy xml response. there is no error just nothing happens

Comment: it is very strange. I have wrote and tested this code on Firefox with Firebug.

Comment: I am sorry but this example is working on all browsers. Firefox Chrome Opera IE9 IE8. I could not test on Safari, however I think it will work on it because Safari is a web-kit browser like Chrome and it is working on Chrome.

Comment: noticed that it works with local file. weird it doesn;t if i pull it from the internet.

Comment: i think i've found the reason http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-widgets-and-ajax-connecting-to-mu/ it seems IE doesn't obey it

Comment: It is weird because I am not using local data, I've got the data with AJAX

Comment: I have downloaded and installed Opera 10.63 for test it. And it is working on Opera too.

Answer (score 0):

First, jQuery itself doesn't really parse XML — it lets the browser do it. It can create a DOM fragment and then it allows you to examine that.  Thus if your xml is in a string you could use:

```
var xml = $(xmlString);
```

Then you could do this:

```
var longName = null;

xml.children('result').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children('type').text() === 'route') {
    var addr = $(this).find('address_component');
    if (addr.find('type').filter(function() { return this.innerHTML === 'administrative_area_level_3'; }).length())
      longName = addr.children('long_name').text();
  }
});
```

or something like that anyway.